# Index error where I think there isn't

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, indexing

```
print "Qual deve ser o tamanho do tabuleiro?"
while 1:
    tamanho = input()
    if 1 < tamanho < 6:
        print "Que o jogo comece!"
        break
    else:
        print "Nao posso usar isso como um tabuleiro..."
numeros = tamanho*tamanho-1
x = [range(0,tamanho)]
y = [range(0,tamanho)]
i = 0
while i < tamanho:
    x[i-1] = y[:]
    i = i + 1
```

I keep getting an index error

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I am trying to make a matrix with y as the column and x as the row. I tried for loops, while loops... almost everything, can someone help me?
P.S.: I'm still learning, so be patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = [range(0,tamanho)]
```

This makes `x` a 1-element list whose only element is a `tamanho`-element list. The `y` line is similar. That's not what you want. If you want an m-by-n matrix, use an m-by-n nested list:

```
matrix = [[0]*n for i in xrange(m)]
```

`[0]*n` makes an n-element list full of zeros, and the list comprehension makes a list of `m` of those.

Comment: Thank you very much! now i realized my mistake, well, sorry for that.